# Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependency'

Tags: java, spring, maven, mybatis

I am new to the concept. I don't understand what the error is.
I use the same version in my xml as in my pom file.
I want to set mybatis with spring (intellij)
I tried searching, so if you add  tag to pom.xml, I can download the library automatically and know the setting is possible.
I already have added [mybatis-3.4.5.jar] to lib.

This is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>GRU</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>


        <!-- MyBatis -->
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>

        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>

        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>

        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

</project>
```

and this is the error message:

```
invalid content was found starting with element ‘dependency’. One of "http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0"parent,
http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":name, "http:/mavenapache.org/POM/400":description, "http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":url,
"http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":prerequisites, "http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":issueManagement,
"http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":ciManagment, "http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":inceptionYear,
"http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":mailingLists, "http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":developers,
“http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":contributors, "http://mavenapacheorg/POM/4.0.0":licenses, "http://mavenapache.org/POM/400":scm ,
“http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":organization, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":build, "http://mavenapache.org/POM/400":profiles, “http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":modules, http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":repositories, “http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":plugin Repositories,"http://mavenapache.org/POM/400":dependencies, “http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":reports, http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":reporting, “http://mavenapache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencyManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":distributionManagement
http://mavenapache.org/POM/40.0.":properties)’ is expected.
```

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Did you try reading through the maven documentation before posting this question? You need a `dependencies` tag followed by one `dependency` tag per dependency..

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `<dependencies>` and create a `<dependency>` for each library:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- MyBatis -->
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have put all of your dependencies inside of a single `<dependency>` tag. Each of them should have their own `<dependency>` tag, enclosed in a `<dependencies>` tag. For example:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version>
  <dependency>

  ...

</dependencies>
```